# CMake test for processor feature

Tags: linux, cmake

I am wondering if it is possible for CMake to run tests like one might run with a configure script.  Specifically I want to test if the system I am compiling on has support for the rdtscp instruction.

I am using Linux and if I were using a configure script I could do something like:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | head -n 19 | tail -1 | grep -c rdtscp
```

which would give me `0` if the rdtscp feature was not present or a `1` if it were.  I could then use this to determine whether to #define RDTSCP.  I'm wondering if it's possible to do something similar with CMake even if it's not completely portable (I'm only running under Linux I'm not using Visual Studio, etc.).

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea to check this in compile-time as the binary would only work reliably on the machine/CPU you compiled on. It is probably a better approach to detect this in runtime using cpuid instruction (assuming this is x86 you're talking about).

Comment: I'm only using this feature for performance analysis during testing, but some systems that I have have support for rdtscp and some don't.  I agree that shipping a binary under these circumstances would be a bad idea.

Comment: Why use -c in the grep?  Just do: if sed -n 19p /proc/cpuinfo | grep rdtscp > /dev/null; then echo rdtscp available; fi

Comment: Thanks, I agree that's better.  But the main thing I'm interested in is whether there's a good way to incorporate that with running CMake.  I know it would be possible with something like a configure script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
execute_process(COMMAND cat /proc/cpuinfo
    COMMAND head -n 19
    COMMAND tail -1
    COMMAND grep -c rdtscp
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE OUT)
```

Comment: Selecting line 19 exactly makes this brittle.  On my desktop (Linux 4.20 on i7-6700k), that line is `wp              : yes`.  Instead use `COMMAND grep -l '^flags[[:space:]]*:.*rdtscp' /proc/cpuinfo`.  Or just `grep -l rdtscp /proc/cpuinfo`, but requiring a match in the `flags   :` line will prevent any possible false-positive.  (To be even more belt-and-suspenders, you could require space before/after).  Using `-l` gets grep to exit after the first match, in case you were using head/tail as an optimization to avoid processing more lines on massively multi-core systems like Xeon Phi?

Answer (score 1):

Selecting line 19 exactly makes this brittle.  On my desktop (Linux 4.20 on i7-6700k), that line is

```
wp              : yes
```

**Instead use `grep`'s pattern-matching ability to check for the `flags\t\t:` line.**

`grep -l '^flags[[:space:]]*:.*rdtscp' /proc/cpuinfo` prints the filename and exits with success after the first match.  Or prints nothing and exists with failure status if it doesn't find a match.

I don't know CMake, but based on the other answer presumably you'd use

```
execute_process(COMMAND grep -l '^flags[[:space:]]*:.*rdtscp' /proc/cpuinfo
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE OUT)
```

---

The simpler version of this is just `grep -l rdtscp /proc/cpuinfo`, but requiring a match in the `flags   :` line will prevent any possible false-positive.  (To be even more belt-and-suspenders, you could require space or end of line before/after, maybe with PCREgrep for zero-width assertions.  In case some future feature flag like `XYZrdtscpABC` that can be present without RDTSCP support becomes a thing in the future.  Or like `broken_rdtscp`).  Or we could just assume that `rdtscp` is never at the end of the a line and look for `^flags.*:.* rdtscp`.

Using `-l` gets grep to exit after the first match, in case you were using head/tail as an optimization to avoid processing more lines on massively multi-core systems like Xeon Phi?  It will still read the whole file if there's no match for `rdtscp`, but probably any massively-multi-core system will have RDTSCP.  And grep is *very* fast anyway.