# run nm | grep commands with cmake execute_process?

Tags: cmake, command

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CMake test for processor feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994255/cmake-test-for-processor-feature)

Im trying to run the following command with cmake execute_process:

```
nm /home/cquiros/GOBLET/tools/3rdParty/shapelib/libshp.a | grep 'DBFReorderFields'
```

But I always command not found. This is the code:

```
SET (CMD "nm")
SET (CMDA "${SHAPELIB_LIBRARY} | grep 'DBFReorderFields'")

execute_process(COMMAND ${CMD} ${CMDA} RESULT_VARIABLE rv)
```

${SHAPELIB_LIBRARY} = /home/cquiros/GOBLET/tools/3rdParty/shapelib/libshp.a . The result should be empty or "000000000000358d T DBFReorderFields"

Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: Almost identical question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994255/cmake-test-for-processor-feature

Comment: Yes! That question answered my problem. Thanks!